# Android Studio sample programm Error

Tags: android

I have this error when working in Android Studio. Please help me. I am new to android studio.

[image]

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer

Comment: Perhaps the `res/values/dimens.xml` file is missing in your project or doesn't include the expected identifiers(?)

Comment: As a  quick solution remove all those lines . And read about [Android Resource structure](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) .

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549587/failed-linking-file-resource-i-am-getting-this-error-even-after-trying-all-po?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you copied all these lines from another project that you found online.  
In the project where these lines originally come from there is a file `dimens.xml` in `res` folder which contains all these `@dimen/...` values. These are numeric values and they are used to set the padding of your Layout
You must copy this file in your project too or just delete the first 4 red underlined lines.  
As for the 5th line you may leave it like this:

```
tools.context=".MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

1) create dimens file It's located in res/values/dimens , here's what a sample of the file look like:

```
 <resources>
     <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
     <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
     <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
 </resources>
```

2) Make activity context like this:

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```