# What to do when code no longer recognizes Drawable folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

So I mistakenly deleted the entire Drawable folder, I immediately pressed undo and the folder is now back in its original place. However, it is not recognised anymore in code.

What can I do? I am desperate right now.

I tried rebuilding the project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoTJK.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain more in detail? Also, Add an image of the error that is showing.

Comment: Yes, so I deleted the entire Drawable folder, which was found under app/src/main/res/drawable path. I pressed undo right after, so the folder its back in its original place. I am not getting and error, but my resources are not visible in the project anymore. Here, for example, I have the lock.png file in the drawable folder, but it is not recognised in the code. I thought maybe I can do something for the drawable folder to be recognized again.

Comment: try rebuilding the project

Comment: I did but it still doesnt take any drawable resources. I tried moving them to another folder and reference that folder but I get this error: /layout/activity_register.xml:43: error: '@drawable3/search' is incompatible with attribute drawableTop (attr) reference|color.
error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: Did you try the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48549587/failed-linking-file-resources) ?